# Devise a function to count the sum of a series of integers 1...N, with alternating (+) and (-) operators, using the recursive method

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

As per the title, I've been given this task to solve. While it is easy to do this using a traditional loop, I am still lost on how this could be achieved using recursion. Any help regarding this will be appreciated!

Here are the expected results:

```
Input: 4
Output: -2
Explanation: 1 -2 + 3 - 4 = -2

Input 9 
Output: -3
Explanation: 1 - 2 + 3 - 4 + 5 - 6 + 7 - 8 + 9 = 5
```

Comment: You could also do this without a loop: `n // 2 + 1 if n % 2 else -(n // 2)`

Comment: @SvenMarnach: if the exercise demands recursion, a loop is irrelevant.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Tail recursion is also a loop. But more importantly, I know that this doesn't solve the OP's homework, but it may help other people coming here in the future, or people might just find it interesting for its own sake.

Comment: Tail recursion is a compiler optimization. It is not coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have only one parameter `n`, which is the given input.
2. You need to keep track of the last number used, and the current sum. This can be done using parameters `i` and `sum` respectively.
3. Odd numbers are added, even are subtracted.

Using the above points, you can derive this simple algorithm:

```
total(i, n, sum):
    if i is odd -> sum += i
    else -> sum -= i
    if i == n -> return sum
    else -> return total(i+1, n, sum)

answer = total(1, input, 0)
```

Comment: Testing this algorithm with the question's expected results, an input of 4 and 9 will result in -2 and 5 respectively, which is incorrect. Could there be a mistake I'm not seeing?

Comment: @topinfx The examples you've added are incorrect; both `1` and `2` are being added. One of them should have `-`

Comment: That makes sense. Seems to be an error from the question provider's end.

Comment: @topinfx in that case, this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Use following logic

1. If number is even add
2. If number is odd subtract

Following is code foe the same

```
def summation(n, index=2, total=1):
    """
    Summation of alternate (+) and (-) operator
    :param n: Input number for which you need a summation of alternate (+) and (-) operator
    :param index: Last number which was added in summation.
    :param total: Summation of number
    """
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    if index % 2 == 0:
        total += index
    else:
        total -= index
    if index == n:
        return total
    return summation(n, index + 1, total)


print(summation(4)) #It will print output 4
print(summation(9)) #It will print output -3
```